# CORS Socket Request to Sails Server Throwing 500 Error

Tags: websocket, socket.io, sails.js

I have a cordova app running on angular that uses a sails server as its API endpoint. It is set up to use CORS and everything is working with ajax calls.

I am attempting to connect to the sails server using socket.io. I copied the sails.io.s file from the sails server's assets folder to the cordova app. I modified it so that it connects to 127.0.0.1:1337 and does so successfully. It does not use cookies on the front end and the sails end does not use socket authorization (set in config/sockets.js).

When I call:

```
io.socket.get('/controller/action', function callback(return){

});
```

The return object looks something like this:

```
{
    message: "TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'get'",
    status: 500
}
```

The sails server log doesn't show that it is hitting /controller/action. Does anyone have any experience with using the custom sails io library on a JS client that isn't sails?

Comment: Which version of sails are you running?

Comment: If it's returning a 500 error, it looks like it's at least hitting the server.  Is there a full stack trace you can post for the error?